# Why does Cartopy show an incomplete boundary for the Robinson projection under different central longitude values?

Tags: cartopy

I am trying to use the cartopy (version=0.21.0) package to draw global data map using the Robinson projection. However, when I choose differnt central longitude values for the projection method, the produced figures show asymmetric left & right boundaries in some cases.

Specifically, the figures look correct when I use a central longitude value of -110, -120, -130, but they show asymmetric boundaries as the central longitude value becomes smaller (e.g., -140, -150, -160). I have used the "add_cyclic_point" function to wrap the global data in a zonal direction before drawing. I also tried to set map extent inspired by the answer of @geofisue.The main codes and figures are attached as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr 
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point

fname = 'sst.nc'
with xr.open_dataset(fname) as f:
    sst = f['sst'].isel(time=0)
    sst = sst.sel(lat=slice(-60,60))

lonc = [-110, -120, -130, -140, -150,-160]
for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.subplot(321+i, projection=ccrs.Robinson(central_longitude=lonc[i]))
    
    # wrap the global 
    wsst, wlon = add_cyclic_point(sst, coord=sst.lon.data)
    handle = ax.contourf(wlon, sst.lat, wsst, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_title('lon-cent = {:d}'.format(lonc[i]))
    ax.coastlines(resolution='110m', color='0.7', lw=1)
    ax.axhline(0, ls='--', color='k', lw=0.8)
    #ax.set_global()
    
plt.show()
```

**below are generated figures with asymmetric boundaires marked**.

**1. cartopy-robinson global data with no set_global option**
[image: cartopy-robinson global data with no set_global option]

**2. cartopy-robinson latitude-sliced data with no extent setting**
[image: cartopy-robinson latitude-sliced data with no extent setting]

**3. cartopy-robinson latitude-sliced data with set_global() option**
[image: cartopy-robinson latitude-sliced data with set_global() option]

I would expect the figures to have exactly the same symmetrical left and right boundaries under different central longitudes even with latitude-sliced data.

All suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with the results you get and identified in the images?

Comment: Hi swatchai, I posted the figures in the link above. In map with a center value of -140, the left boundary become somewhat straight near the equator (enclosed by red mark) while the right boundary is a smooth curve (enclosed by  blue mark). similiar situations are only observed when the center longitude less than -140.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is related to extent of the plot due to the data used. I am not using data, but add a `ax.set_global()` in order to show the whole globe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point

lonc = [-110, -120, -130, -140, -150,-160]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.subplot(321+i, projection=ccrs.Robinson(central_longitude=lonc[i]))
    ax.set_title('lon-cent = {:d}'.format(lonc[i]))
    ax.coastlines(resolution='110m', color='0.7', lw=1)
    ax.axhline()
    ax.set_global()
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I've done it with some data, and this is indeed the solution.

Comment: Thank you for you clues, but if I would like to draw a regional data, say, 60S-60N, then the ax.set_global() is less appropriate, which displays regional data on the global map. I also tried ax.set_extent() or just slice the data with no settings on the map extent, both doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @ChaoLiu Again, this is due to the lack of data over africa, Cartopy is getting the extent from the data and this is why it's happening. So you need 1) set global or 2) set manually the extent to be [lon-cent - 180, lon-cent + 180] (taking into account that 181 -> -179, of course).